# How to parse elements with only one class name included using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

For this html:

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="one two three" date="20130121">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="one" date="20130122">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="one two" date="20130123">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="one" date="20130124">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to extract the date element with `class = "one"` only, so that if class is included "one" but having other class is not correct.
My expect answer should be `date="20130122"` and `date="20130124"`

I tried to use:

```
Element outestDiv = doc.getElementById("list");
Elements eachDayBox = outestDiv.select("div.one");
```

But `eachDayBox.size()` return 4 but not 2. So how to extract with class only "one"??
Also, how to get element in "date"??

Comment: Try `div[class="one"]` as the selector.

Comment: there is some error when I changed to outestDiv.select("div[class="one"]");

Comment: after I changed to outestDiv.select("div[class='one']");, the size is zero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[attribute=value]` in select

```
Elements eachDayBox = outestDiv.select("div[class=one]"); //class only equal to one
```

[Reference](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: how about `.select("div[class].one");`

Comment: Or `.select("div[class$=one]")` class ending with one

Comment: yes, I edited your answer, thanks!! But how to extract date??

Comment: posted as diff ans , so others can see

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23614/discussion-between-techexchange-and-jjlin)

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "one");
for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++){
    Element tmp=elements.get(i);
    System.out.println(tmp.attr("date"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the Date value

`String date = eachDayBox .attr("date");`